# Sharing a session between a WKWebView and Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mobile-safari

I have an iOS app that authenticates for api access and I have a request to throw the user into safari, not a WKWebView but still keep them authenticated.

Is there anyway to securely share the session between an iOS app and full safari?

I have looked into WKProcesspools but I am not sure that will quite do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about WKProcesspools, but you can share the session using Query parmaters.
Format your weburl to include verification token as a query parameter.

When you verify user via API, you must get the token from response. Pass this token as a query parameter in your url and redirect to Safari.

```
URL - https://www.example.com/page1
URL with token - https://www.example.com/page1?token=asdfv12324fvfropfc23as
```

Extra care to prevent copy/paste of token:

When creating token, pass IP Address or MAC Address as parameter of your API and based on these addresses you can check if the request is coming from same address. This will take care of the device authentication.

Comment: We did come up with this type of solution on our own but it basically what we ended up doing so I am marking it as the accepted answer,